# Passing the actual path in File Save Data

Tags: feeds, files

I have the following line in my script, but it fails to save the file in site/default/files folder. Is it possible I can replace `public://feedproducts.xml` with an actual absolute path to the files directory?

```
$file = file_save_data($sxe->asXML(),"public://feedproducts.xml",FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

This script runs from the command line, and is inside a sub-directory inside the root. It also loads Drupal Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that the script was running from a subdirectory. Calling `chdir(DRUPAL_ROOT)` before `file_save_data()` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

No. Read the docs on [`file_save_data()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7), it needs a valid URI. otherwise it will not work.

If `file_save_data()` is returning false with the above code, you're better off investigating why. It's likely a permission or some other problem preventing file I/O on that directory.

Comment: You are correct; however, I haven't been able to pinpoint what the issue is. I can save data using `file_put_contents` but not `file_save_date`. The permissions and path both seem to be ok. Any chance this might have anything to do with me running php 5.6?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any odd behavior with PHP 5.6 & the Drupal file API. I'd look through watchdog (and Apache too if it's logging anything) for any telltale signs from Drupal/PHP. Failing that, follow the flow of execution in [file_unmanaged_save_data()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_unmanaged_save_data/7). Somewhere in there the save operation is failing.

Answer (score 1):

All systems have a file stream wrapper, as far as I know, so try:

```
$uri = 'file:///absolute/path/to/file.ext';
file_save_data($sxe->asXml, $uri, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```